# SQL Maintenance Plan sends mail when no mail configured

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job, maintenance-plan, database-mail

I have a Maintenance plan under SQL Server 2008 R2 which runs at midnight. Within this maintenance task, there is no notify operator task. Within the SQL Agent job that executes the maintenance plan, there is no email alert. However, every time this job runs, I receive an email from SQL Server with the subject 'SQL Server Message'. I cannot understand why this mail keeps sending. Here's what the mail body starts with:

> Microsoft(R) Server Maintenance Utility (Unicode) Version 10.50.1617
>   Report was generated on "SERVERNAME".
>   Maintenance Plan: My Maintenance Plan
>   Duration: 00:01:02
>   Status: Succeeded.
>   Details:

Any ideas why this mail is sending, and where I should update the configuration so it only sends on failure or not at all?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally found where this is configured. When you right click and modify a maintenance plan within SQL Server Management Studio, at the very top of the maintenance plan designer, there is a menu bar with a "Reporting and Logging" button. The option "Send report to an email recipient" was where it was configured.

[image]
[image]